# Add billing_first_name Inside Recent Orders Widget (Woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My widget displays recent Woocommerce orders within the wordpress admin dashboard. It works correctly when I remove the billing_first_name field, but when I add this field it creates an error within the code.

How can I add the billing_first_name field to work correctly within my admin widget so it displays all values.

```
  /**
 * Add a widget to the dashboard.
 *
 */
function wc_orders_dashboard_widgets() {
    wp_add_dashboard_widget(
                 'wc_order_widget_id',         // Widget slug.
                 'Cartlog Orders',         // Title.
                 'wc_orders_dashboard_widget_function' // Display function.
        );  
}
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'wc_orders_dashboard_widgets' );

/**
 * Pulls the order information to the dashboard widget.
 */
function wc_orders_dashboard_widget_function() {    
    $args   = array( 
            'post_type'         => 'shop_order',
            'post_status'       => 'All',  //Other options available choose one only: 'wc-pending', 'wc-processing', 'wc-on-hold', 'wc-cancelled', 'wc-refunded', 'wc-failed'
            'posts_per_page'    => 10     //Change this number to display how many orders you want to see 
          );
    $orders = get_posts( $args );
    if( count( $orders ) > 0 ) {
        ?>      
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <th><?php _e( 'Order Id', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th><?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th><?php _e( 'Billing Name', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th><?php _e( 'Status', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            </tr>
        <?php       
        foreach ( $orders as $key => $value ) {
            
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <?php
                
                $order   =   new WC_Order( $value->ID );
                // 1. Get the order ID
                if ( $order ) {             
                          echo '<a href="'. admin_url( 'post.php?post=' . absint( $order->id ) . '&action=edit' ) .'" >' . $order->get_order_number() . '</a>';
                ?>
                
                </td>
                <td>    
                
                <?php
                    // 2. Get the order total
                    echo esc_html( wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_total() ) );
                }
                ?>
                </td>
                <td>    
                
                <?php
                    // 3. Get the billing name
                    echo esc_html(wc_get_order_status_name($order>get_billing_first_name() ) );
                }
                ?>
                </td>
                <td>                
                
                <?php
                    // 4. Get the order status
                    echo esc_html( wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) );
                }
                ?>
                </td>                   
            </tr>
            <?php           
        }
        ?></table>
<?php

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing the if statement after you've displayed the order total and then have closing braces duplicated for `3` and `4`. You're also passing all of your display values through `wc_get_order_status_name()` which is only appropriate for the order status.

## Getting the latest orders

Before fixing the issues highlighted above, it's worth starting with your method for retrieving the latest orders. You're using `get_posts()` which may work at the moment but isn't advisable. WooCommerce is moving to custom tables so any code that assumes orders are a post will break in the future. You're better off using the functionality that WooCommerce provides.

```
$orders = wc_get_orders([
    'limit' => 10,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
]);
```

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query

A nice benefit of this approach is that you get back an array of `WC_Order` objects as opposed to posts which then need to be converted.

## Displaying orders

```
foreach ( $orders as $order ) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php printf( 
                '<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>',
                $order->get_edit_order_url(),
                $order->get_order_number()
            ); ?>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $order->get_total(); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $order->get_billing_first_name(); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php }
```